# Как убрать пункт из хлебных крошек woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

На сайте имеются хлебные крошки такого вида:

> Тест>Каталог>Товары>Программное обеспечение>ЛабМенеджер

Я использую плагин Breadcrumb NavXT.

Нужно убрать "Товары". Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В настройках вордпресс нужно настроить показ ссылок. Вот там измените иерархию показа и хлебные крошки подстроятся автоматически.

Comment: не получается, менял по разному хлебные крошки не поменялись, это может быть из-за того, что у меня своя тема?

Comment: Нет, скорее дело в плагине для хлебных крошек. Потестируйте другие плагины, возможно дело в этом.

Comment: в общем  в настройках Breadcrumb NavXT поменял